# Combining cells as a result in excel

Tags: excel

I have the following columns in excel sheet .

```
A            B              
Name      Address         
A          Houston
B          Texas
```

I need to introduce one more column where I need to combine both A and B as:

```
A           B             C
Name      Address       Calculated
A          Houston       A  Houston 1
B          Texas         B  Texas   1
```

1 is always harcoded for all cells. What would be the formula to achieve this in excel?

Comment: Concatenate the cells: `=A2&" "&B2&" 1"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CONCATENATE()` function.

```
=CONCATENATE(A2," ",B2," 1")
```

[image]